# PHP Passing $_FILES and $_POST as parameters to function

Tags: php, file, upload

I searched online for a code that does PHP image upload using ajax. I found the code attached below. The issue is that I changed few things (minor tweaks) to make it work on my server. Originally it was just a php page (not a class or function) that handles the data posted from form. I made it into class then function. I am following OOP now. I thought the best way to do things in the conversion from procedural to OOP was to pass $_FILES and $_POST to a method and inside deal with them. I think this didn't work. Look at the example and please advise on how to go forward.

```
function uploadImageChosen($_FILES, $_POST){
            $path = "../uploads/images/";
            $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
            $connectionInstance = new ConnectionClass();
            $connectionInstance->connectToDatabase();
            $imgName;
            $imgURL;
            $imgSize;
            $imgDir = $_POST['directory'];
            if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
            {
                $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
                $imgSize = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
                if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                        if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $imgName = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$imgName))
                            {
                                $imgURL = $path.$imgName;
                                $connectionInstance->query("INSERT INTO imagesupload(id, title, url, size, directory) VALUES (null, '$imgName','$imgURL', '$imgSize', '$imgDir')");
                                //echo "<img src='uploads/".$imgName."'  class='preview'>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "failed";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "Invalid file format..";   
                    }
            }else{
                echo "Please select image..!";
            }           

          }//end of if      

        }//end of function
```

As to the page where the class function is being called, here it is:

```
<?php
    require_once("../classes/UploadImages.php");
    $uploadInstance = new UploadImages();
    $uploadInstance->uploadImageChosen($_FILES, $_POST);
    //header("LOCATION:portfolio.php");
?>
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What is the expected behavior, and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: image is moved to directory upload/images and img data stored in db

Comment: Is that the expected behavior or the actual behavior?

Comment: The script I downloaded did that correctly. And I didn't change logic more than storage places. So actual I guess

Comment: You're not giving much information, are you getting any errors? Are the files not being saved? Is the data not stored in db?

Comment: If I got errors I could fix them so none. the answer is no to all questions

Comment: Which `else` statement fires ?? Also, your filesize check will never be enforeced because `$size` does not exist. It should be `$imgSize`.

Comment: got the problem solved. I will share the answer below :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_POST` and `$_FILES` are superglobal arrays, they are always available, and redefining them in a function or method is a bad idea.

You can do something like this:

```
$uploadInstance->uploadImageChosen();
```

..

```
function uploadImageChosen(){
           $path = "../uploads/images/";
           $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
...
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
...
```

Or if you need copies in the local scope do it like this:

```
$uploadInstance->uploadImageChosen($_FILES, $_POST);
```

..

```
function uploadImageChosen($files, $post){
               $path = "../uploads/images/";
               $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
...
$name = $files['photoimg']['name'];
...
```

Comment: Will this work even if the call of the class function is in a seperate file than the page that the form submits to?

Comment: Yes. Superglobal array available everywhere. Calling a function with a parameter, the second option, does not depend on where the function defined.

Comment: I got the problem. I didn't do your edits yet but the solution was different. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"` from the IF-statement, and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The script above has a problem which was not detected in error log. The problem was first presented when I instantiated the connection class. I should have created another variable that would receive the open connection for querying to work That was solved and data now present in the DB. The second problem was the JPG format was not in array of acceptable types, so I added that along with jpg (variations). This made the file actually transfer to upload folder. Thank you all for support and sorry for the inconvenience :)